# What does this line mean in slick?

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.4

I was looking into the play-slick3 demo and I saw the definition of this table

```
  private class ProjectsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Project](tag, "PROJECT") {

    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    def name = column[String]("NAME")

    def * = (id, name) <> (Project.tupled, Project.unapply)
    def ? = (id.?, name.?).shaped.<>({ r => import r._; _1.map(_ => Project.tupled((_1.get, _2.get))) }, (_: Any) => throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))    
  }
```

What does the last line mean? I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation or the API

Comment: I have no idea, but I will say that that is possibly the most unpleasant-looking line of Scala I've ever seen.

Comment: what version of slick are you using?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment at http://www.developmentalmadness.com/2016/02/23/scala-connecting-to-postgres-via-slick-3/

> Maps whole row to an option. Useful for outer joins.